# Is it possible for a notification to increment the badge count rather than set it to an absolute value?

Tags: ios

I'm queueing local notifications and setting the badge count to 1.

If I queue a few then exit the app then when they trigger each one of them sets the badge count to 1, rather than incrementing it. i.e. suppose I queue 3 then after all of them fire the badge count on the app will show as 1.

Is there a way that the badge count can increment by one when each fires?

Examining applicationIconBadgeNumber when the notification is set is not an option - because consider a scenario like this:

App schedules notification A for 1 minutes, current badge count is 0, so notification.count = 1

App schedules notification B for 10 minutes, last badge count is 1, so notification.count = 2

App schedules notification C for 5 minutes, last badge count is 2, so notification.count = 3

But notification C fires before B, so when it fires the badge count would be set to 3 which is incorrect, then when B fires the count goes to 2 which is also incorrect.

If there's no automatic way of incrementing the count then the app would have to implement a complicated scheme where it remembers everything its queued and the time of each.
Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber];

    if (num == 0) {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
    }

    else if (num >= 1) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:num + 1];
    }
```

I think this will solve it.

Comment: Thanks but re-read the scenario, this will only work if A is 1 minute, B is  5 minutes and C is 10 minutes, i.e. increasing. But B is 10 minutes and C is 5 minutes.